# How to make up for missed salat for years?

Tags: quran, fiqh, salat-qada

Lately i discovered the importance of salat and it will be first thing to be asked on judgement day and i have missed so much due to negligence. How do one make up for years of missed salat? What does Quran says about it? 
Some people say to say "Subhna Rabi Alla" in sajdah when saying fard, and some says to say "Subhna Rabi Azeem"in qaza namaz, is it correct?
People read salat without understanding its meaning, does it get accepted?

Comment: These are three distinct question and should be posed separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want an answer only from Quran, than the Quran doesn't give permission to making up prayer once it's missed, as Allaah said prayer is enjoined on us at fixed times.

So once the prayer is missed, it's lost forever.  Therefore, you have to repent and not to miss or neglect the future prayers.  Allaah forgives and is merciful.

- Saying Subhaana Rabbial Azim in qaza and Subhana Rabbial 'Ala in fard only, is not correct.  They're to be said in both fard, qaza and nafl prayers.  All the time in every ruku you say Subhaana Rabbial Azim and in every sajda you say Subhana Rabbial 'Ala.  But this is not mentioned in the Quran.
- The purpose of prayer is to remember Allaah.  As long as they're remembering Allaah and not thinking of other things and following the way the Prophet prayed, the salaat is acceptable.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, I must say that I will disagree with the notion that a missed prayer can not be made up for. Quran does not say if you miss a prayer or a good deed, the opportunity is gone forever and it has not been banned to try to make up for what is missed. Hence, believe it is possible to make up not just for salah but for any prayer. This is also inline with Quran's encouragement to try to do more prayers and good deeds or Allah's constant reminder that we are given another chance until the moment of our own death or seeing the signs of Doomsday has become clear to us.

As for the question, I too had the same concern about missed salahs. It was bugging me for a very long time and I believe Allah has already made it possible for us to be able to make up for what we have missed over the years. I wrote about it today: 
https://www.facebook.com/notes/murat-kurt/ramadan-2018-looking-back-and-future/10156467646199532/

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help] for more information about our site and model. What you think is not what we are looking for we look for well elaborated answers which are focused on answering the actual question and any claim to be supported by evidences (see [answer]).

Comment: So you deleted my comments, worked with Jamila to make sure my response to all questions on this matter -which millions of people are trying to find a solution- have been down voted until Jamila posted an answer?Here is my question to you: if I was right with my reasoning and you prevented people from benefiting it, do you think you will not be held responsible?